# How do I map different server names to differrent DirectoryIndex in PHP Symfony?

Tags: php, apache, symfony1

Symfony uses the following typical **.htaccess** file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and I have this as my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName jobeet.loc
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/jobeet/web"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>

Alias /sf "C:/wamp/lib/symfony-1.4.1/data/web/sf"
<Directory "C:/wamp/lib/symfony-1.4.1/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

The above works perfectly, but I want to know how to map and additional debugging url, *http://jobeet.dev* to automatically serve the frontend_dev.php file so I can use urls like:
**http://jobeet.dev/jobs/...**
instead of
**http://jobeet.dev/frontend_dev.php/jobs/...**
to map to the debug .php file in the framework.

I tried adding a duplicate of the vhost entry and simply changing the servername and directoryindex to
**ServerName jobeet.dev**
**DirectoryIndex frontend_dev.php**
but understandably this does not work, as I believe I would need to check the URL in the .htaccess to do this?

Can anyone offer some advice regarding this?

Thanks in advance!
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add jobeet.dev as a ServerAlias in your current VirtualHost so it can share the same hosting configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName jobeet.loc
    ServerAlias jobeet.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/jobeet/web"
    ....
```

Don't forget to restart Apache when you're done.

Next, turn on no_script_name in your dev configuration in `apps/frontend/config/settings.yml`:

```
dev:
  .settings:
    no_script_name: true
```

Now your dev web controller (frontend_dev.php) won't show up in your auto-generated URLs (from link_to(), url_for(), etc).

Finally, set up a RewriteRule for your dev domain before your production controller comes in to play to route everything coming in at jobeet.dev to your dev web controller:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  ...
  ...
  RewriteCond %{HOST_NAME} ^jobeet\.dev$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend_dev.php [QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to map all needed hosts (`jobeet.loc`, `jobeet.dev`, etc) to `SF_DIR/web`, set `index.php` as dir-index (as you did) and in that file just run particular app with a particular env depending on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Hope I described good to make an idea clear.